# Extremely slow Apollo gateway / server responses

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, typeorm, apollo-server

We're facing some challenging performance issues with some queries taking an extremely long time to respond, often in excess of 20s and frequently timing out at 60s. These extreme timings cannot be reproduced in local dev environments, even when using load testing tools like graphql-bench and autocannon. These same queries can also complete in ~500ms.

We have a federated graph setup with an instance of Apollo Gateway (running ~0.24) and 2 instances of Apollo Server (running 3.x) providing subgraphs. All 3 use NestJS 7 on top of Apollo Server + express. Our resolvers use Typeorm to interface with a reasonably large and complex MSSQL database. The database is hugely OP and resource monitors never get over 10% RAM & CPU.

The API servers are hosted on AWS ECS and are generously resources. Like the DB server, the CPU and RAM usage average out at 10-20%, although the CPU does spike to >100% sometimes.

Tracing in Apollo Studio appears to show some high level resolvers "hanging" or "waiting" for long periods of time. ie. 27s out of a 30s response.

We do have some N+1 issues and we've made some limited use of Dataloader in places to resolve those issues, although we can definitely implement it more. I'm not convined that the N+1 issues are responsible for the extreme timings though due to the wild range of those timing and the inconsistencies of them.

Does this scenario sound famililar to anyone? Does anyone have any ideas or pointers how we might go about tracking down the root issue and debugging it? We're a bit stumped tbh, especially as the issues seem to be impossible to repro locally.

Comment: @W.S. , sorry, I probably wasn’t clear: the CPU spikes are not from the database server but are from the ECS tasks running the gateway and subgraphs. As far as I’m aware, the database server barely ever breaks a sweat. Some extra info: at peak times the throughput to the graph is ~400rpm max. The gateway server has 6 instances in ECS and the main, problematic subgraph server has 9 instances. Very likely over the top but reducing that number has an obvious negative effect on response times

Comment: Just a very general idea: if disk space is too low, especially for the database, then it might be surprising that you still get a result at all.

Comment: I'm also seeing this -- barely any resources used up, resolvers eventually get called but there are significant gaps between the first level resolvers (and when they finish according to db call traces) and when the next level resolvers are invoked. When tracing individual "willResolveField" spans, I saw 100ms pass before the resolver was actually invoked (as seen by db calls). I'm using typegraphql-prisma with no middleware or authorization, as well, which is as close to bare as I can see. (To be clear, this "overhead" gets worse as the response size scales up)

Comment: @MattKindy we found that we have a many more open MSSQL db connections than we would have expected. Our working theory is that the slow resolvers are waiting on db connections but it seems we're not releasing them properly in our code. We use TypeORM and by default, it limits the max number of available pool connections to 10 so we're going to up that limit to 1000 and then rework the queryrunner code to ensure the connections are released properly. I'll post the results here once we've done it.

Comment: I ended up doing a quick PoC of our server using Mercurius to see if it really was something apollo-server specific. I found that wasn't the case (I was seeing similar results at that point). After profiling the server, I saw results that seem to be consistent with this open issue for graphql-js https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/2262 (also of note: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/3815 but I swapped this out and wasn't our particular problem)